# Get request body dotnet6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have some logging middleware to get request body in aspnet API that was working fine for dotnet5. But since I upgraded to dotnet6, I noticed that HttpContext.Request.Body has zero length.

My code so far:

```
context.Request.EnableBuffering();
await using var tmpStream = RecyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(tmpStream); // context.Request.Body.Length is 0
```

Is there some way to get request body in dotnet6?
I read there's a Microsoft middleware to log request, but I would prefer to use our implementation, which have custom features.